# Mandrill - CCed E-Mails Are Sent Separately

Tags: mandrill

I make send request API calls with the following `to` property:

```
"to": [
    {
        "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
        "type": "to"
    },
    {
        "email": "another-email@example.com",
        "type": "cc"
    },
    {
        "email": "3rd-email@example.com",
        "type": "cc"
    }
]
```

I expect Mandrill to send out one e-mail based on the properties in the request above where the `To` field is `recipient.email@example.com` and the `CC` field is `another-email@example.com; 3rd-email@example.com`.

Instead Mandrill sends out three separate e-mails where every individual e-mail is designated to one person and the `CC` fields are treated as `To` fields.

Is there anyway to get Mandrill to send out one e-mail that respects the CC addresses as actual CC recipients?

Answer (score 0):

Try set `preserve_recipients` option to `true`. According to [their documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-new-message/) it indicates

> whether or not to expose all recipients in to "To" header for each email